# How do I approach $\int e^{\sin x}\cdot(1+\tan x\sec x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

$$\int e^{\sin x}\cdot(1+\tan x\sec x)dx$$
I tried the trig identity
$$1+\tan x\sec x=1+\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x}$$
Which gives
$$\frac{\cos^2x+\sin x}{\cos^2x}$$
This is where I stopped

Comment: Hint: Integrate by parts. For the choice of "parts", consider that $\tan x\sec x$ has a simple antiderivative.

Comment: Hint: $1 + \frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x} = \frac{(\sin x)'}{\cos x} - \frac{(\cos x)'}{\cos^2 x} = \frac{(\sin x)'}{\cos x} + \left(\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)' $

Answer (score 3):

Note

$$ (\sec x)'=\tan x \sec x $$

Thus

\begin{align}
I&=\int e^{\sin x}\,dx+\int e^{\sin x}\,d(\sec x) \\
&=\int e^{\sin x}\,dx+e^{\sin x}\sec x-\int e^{\sin x}\,dx \\
&=e^{\sin x}\sec x+C \\
\end{align}